# Python bokeh show only every second categorical ticker

Tags: python, axis, bokeh, ticker

How can I set for a `CategoricalAxis` not to show every ticker but just every second or third one? Let say I have 20 categorics on `x-axis`. I tried this but it does not work:

```
ticker = CategoricalTicker(desired_num_ticks=10)
xaxis = CategoricalAxis(ticker=ticker)
my_fig.add_layout(xaxis, 'above')
```

It shows all my tickers :(

---

EDIT:
It would be great to show only every second label as well...

Thank you!

Comment: This capability is not built in to Bokeh. Categorical names can be completely arbitrary, so there's no way, in general, for users to be able infer what any "missing" ones might be. They have to be shown. But, Bokeh is extensible. If you really wanted to do this, you could write a custom extension ticker: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html