# Bokeh : is it possible to create glyphs based on condition with ColumnDataSource same as with pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, bokeh

Well I am creating rectangles in Bokeh, which are based on condition :

```
rect1 = p.rect(df.index[df.Close > df.Open],(df["Open"][df.index[df.Close > df.Open]]+df["Close"][df.index[df.Close > df.Open]])/2, hours_12, (df["Close"][df.index[df.Close > df.Open]]-df["Open"][df.index[df.Close > df.Open]]),fill_color="#CCCCCC", line_color="black")
```

So it will create rect only if value in "Close" column is higher than "Open" value. Everething works fine without creating ColumnDataSource. If I try to do it with ColumnDataSource it doesn't work so I'm like: Hey, its ok, I am gonna stick with pandas here.

The problem is when trying to use HoverTool. It doesn´t like pandas DataFrame. So I am not able to have both conditions and hover tool. I have to pick one of them.

Is there a solution to that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. The positional arguments of `rect` are `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`, `angle`, and `dilate`.

Just create a data source with the required columns and pass the columns' names in place of your data:

```py
index = df.index[df.Close > df.Open]
close =df.loc[index, 'Close']
open =df.loc[index, 'Open']
cds = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=index, y=(open + close) / 2, width=hours_12, height=(close - open)))
rect1 = p.rect('x', 'y', 'width', 'height', source=cds, fill_color="#CCCCCC", line_color="black")
```

Note that the columns can have any names. The only thing that matters is that you use the same names in the arguments to `rect`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am having problem implementing that. Getting ValueError: expected an element of ColumnData(String, Seq(Any)), got {'x': DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-02', '2020-01-03',...       Seems like ColumnDataSource doesn´t like dates or I am doing something wrong. If you could come up with something it would mean a lot to me.

Comment: Right. And that's exactly why you should provide at least some example of the data in questions, so I could at least run the code to test it. :) For Bokeh, the `DatetimeIndex` class is opaque, it seems. Try to get its `.values` and put them in `'x'`. If that doesn't work, convert the array into POSIX timestamps - that's what Bokeh ends up using either way.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found a solution mainly thanks to this: [How to properly handle datetime and categorical axes in bokeh/holoviews heatmap plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56953630/how-to-properly-handle-datetime-and-categorical-axes-in-bokeh-holoviews-heatmap)

My code had two problems : when I was transforming pandas dataframe into `ColumnDataSource` I needed to transform date into datetime object.

```
x_green = [
     date.to_datetime64().astype('M8[ms]').astype('O')
     for date in df_green.index.to_list()
]
```

And afterwards I needed to understand that I can not do the same (math) operation between `ColumnDataSource` columns as it is possible with pandas columns. So I needed to prepare the data (dictionary) from pandas columns, then make a `ColumnDataSource` and then I was allowed to finally use `HoverTool` which was the main thing all the time. Then it finally worked. Whole code is here:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas_datareader import data
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, ColumnDataSource, output_file
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

output_notebook()

start=datetime(2020,1,1)
end=datetime(2020,4,3)
name="NSRGY" #nestle

#getting stock data from yahoo
df=(data.DataReader(name=name,data_source="yahoo",start=start,end=end))

#making two datasets based on criteria 
df_green=df[df.Close > df.Open]
df_red=df[df.Close < df.Open]

#converting date to datetime : otherwise ColumnDataSource is not working
x_green = [
     date.to_datetime64().astype('M8[ms]').astype('O')
     for date in df_green.index.to_list()
]

x_red = [
     date.to_datetime64().astype('M8[ms]').astype('O')
     for date in df_red.index.to_list()
]


#preparing data for each of CDS
data_green= {
    'date':x_green,
    'open':df_green.Open.tolist(),
    'close':df_green.Close.tolist(),
    'y':((df_green.Open + df_green.Close)/2).tolist(),
    'height':((df_green.Close - df_green.Open)).tolist(),
    'low':df_green.Low.tolist(),
    'high':df_green.High.tolist(),
}

data_red= {
    'date':x_red,
    'open':df_red.Open.tolist(),
    'close':df_red.Close.tolist(),
    'y':((df_red.Open + df_red.Close)/2).tolist(),
    'height':((df_red.Close - df_red.Open)).tolist(),
    'low':df_red.Low.tolist(),
    'high':df_red.High.tolist(),
}


source_green=ColumnDataSource(data=data_green)
source_red=ColumnDataSource(data=data_red)

p=figure(x_axis_type="datetime", height=300,sizing_mode="scale_width")
p.title.text = "Candlestick Chart"

hours_12=12*60*60*1000

ciara_green = p.segment(x0="date", y0='low', x1="date", y1='high', color='black', source=source_green)
ciara_red = p.segment(x0="date", y0='low', x1="date", y1='high', color='black', source=source_red)
rect_green = p.rect(x='date',y = 'y', width = hours_12,height = ('height'), fill_color="green", source=source_green)
rect_red = p.rect(x='date',y = 'y', width = hours_12,height = ('height'), fill_color="red", source=source_red)
rect_hover = HoverTool(renderers=[rect_green,rect_red],
                       tooltips=[("Company",name),('Open value','@{open}'),('Close value','@{close}'),('Date','@date{%F}')], formatters={'date':'datetime'})

p.add_tools(rect_hover)

show(p)
```

I suppose there is more elegant way to do this, but this is what I was able to do. 
Remember, the majority of this code is done because of `HoverTool` which requires `ColumnDataSource`. Otherwise it is easily done with pandas dataframe and just two (longer) lines of code which are in my original question. If you are familiar with plotly : is it the same pain to implement hover feature into graph? Thank you