# How do I adjust categorical tickers in Bokeh when using nested categories?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

In a similar vein to the link below, I'd like to adjust the placement of my grid lines using a categorical ticker. However, since I'm using nested categories, I can't get get_ticks to work (as mentioned by bigreddot).

So simply, how do I make this work using nested categories?

[How to show only evey nth categorical tickers in Bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172201/how-to-show-only-evey-nth-categorical-tickers-in-bokeh/49178883#49178883?newreg=36579714085b46a5bb0a2ad6f12a5ec9)

I've tried messing around with a number of other tickers and looking at the ticker source code, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Welcome! It could help a lot if you paste here your minimal but complete and runnable code. This article can help you to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm using nested categories in the fashion described in the bokeh docs [link here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#nested-categories), and I'm using the coffeescript linked in the post above as my basis.